# Eager loading attributes from model associated with another associated model in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I couldn´t think of a way to ask this, but I have the following models:

Coffee, CoffeeGroup and Discounts

Coffee is n to n with CoffeeGroup, CoffeeGroup is n to 1 with Discounts

How can I do eager loading (if possible) to get the coffee with an attribute that is a list of discounts?

Currently, this is almost working:

```
const coffee = await Coffee.findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id,
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: CoffeeGroup,
          through: { attributes: []},
          include: [{
            model: Discount,
          }]
        }
      ]
    });
```

It gives the following results:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Ingredients": 1,
    "Image1": "",
    "Image2": "",
    "NetCost": 1,
    "GrossCost": 1,
    "State": "",
    "SalePrice1": 1,
    "SalePrice2": 1,
    "deletedAt": null,
    "createdAt": "",
    "updatedAt": "",
    "CoffeeGroups": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Test Group",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "createdAt": "2023-08-20T16:24:53.956Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-08-20T16:24:53.956Z",
            "Discounts": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "Name": "Test",
                    "Type": 1,
                    "Amount": 50,
                    "PaidByHost": false,
                    "CoffeeGroupId": 1,
                    "SubhostGroupId": 1,
                    "StartDate": null,
                    "EndDate": null,
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "createdAt": "2023-08-21T02:44:18.108Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-08-21T02:46:57.886Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I would like to skip coffeeGroups and just get an array of discounts that belong to the coffeeGroups that the coffee belongs to. Something like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
    "Name": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Ingredients": 1,
    "Image1": "",
    "Image2": "",
    "NetCost": 1,
    "GrossCost": 1,
    "State": "",
    "SalePrice1": 1,
    "SalePrice2": 1,
    "deletedAt": null,
    "createdAt": "",
    "updatedAt": "",
    "Discounts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Test",
            "Type": 1,
            "Amount": 50,
            "PaidByHost": false,
            "CoffeeGroupId": 1,
            "SubhostGroupId": 1,
            "StartDate": null,
            "EndDate": null,
            "deletedAt": null,
            "createdAt": "2023-08-21T02:44:18.108Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-08-21T02:46:57.886Z"
            }
        ]
}
```